# viewModelScope blocks UI in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

`viewModelScope` blocks UI in Jetpack Compose

I know `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {}` can avoid this problem, but how to use `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {}`?

This is my UI level code

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CountryContent(viewModel: CountryViewModel) {

    SingleRun {
        viewModel.getCountryList()
    }

    val pagingItems = viewModel.countryGroupList.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    // ...
}
```

Here is my ViewModel, `Pager` is my pagination

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class CountryViewModel @Inject constructor() : BaseViewModel() {

    var countryGroupList = flowOf<PagingData<CountryGroup>>()

    private val config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 26, prefetchDistance = 1, initialLoadSize = 26)

    fun getCountryList() {
        countryGroupList = Pager(config) {
            CountrySource(api)
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }

}
```

This is the small package

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SingleRun(onClick: () -> Unit) {

    val execute = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }

    if (execute.value) {
        onClick()
        execute.value = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Compose much yet, so I could be wrong, but this stood out to me.

I don't think your thread is being blocked. I think you subscribed to an empty flow before replacing it, so there is no data to show.

You shouldn't use a `var` property for your flow, because the empty original flow could be collected before the new one replaces it. Also, it defeats the purpose of using `cachedIn` because the flow could be replaced multiple times.

You should eliminate the `getCountryList()` function and just directly assign the flow. Since it is a `cachedIn` flow, it doesn't do work until it is first collected anyway. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).cachedIn(kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope)):

> It won't execute any unnecessary code unless it is being collected.

So your view model should look like:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CountryViewModel @Inject constructor() : BaseViewModel() {

    private val config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 26, prefetchDistance = 1, initialLoadSize = 26)

    val countryGroupList = Pager(config) {
            CountrySource(api)
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }

}
```

...and you can remove the `SingleRun` block from your Composable.

You are not doing anything that would require you to specify dispatchers. The default of Dispatchers.Main is fine here because you are not calling any blocking functions directly anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, your analysis is right, works great.
But what if I want to manually trigger the request?

Comment: You mean what if you want to start the fetch of data before there are necessarily any collectors?

Comment: Yes, such as there are dependent parameters, I need to manually trigger this network request

Comment: What do you mean by dependent parameters? If these parameters trigger collection under the hood, it should be fine as is. I can't think of another reason to manually start it early except to prefetch data before it is requested on-screen, which would only be relevant if your ViewModel exists significantly before this Composable is ever requested. But if there is a need for it, there are a few different strategies you could use, such as 1) custom SharingStarted and `shareIn` instead of `cachedIn`, or 2) a Boolean MutableStateFlow with `flatMapLatest` to your paging flow.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant, where did the `pagingSourceFactory` in the documentation link in your answer come from? I did not understand

Comment: I've never used paging, so I don't know how that part of it works. I was just looking at what kind of Flow `cachedIn` creates. Looks like it is very similar to `shareIn` with `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()` and replay of 1. So if you want to immediately start the upstream flow when the ViewModel is created, you could replace `cachedIn` with: `shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, replay = 1)`